# How to get Google maps for each country name

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I 'm retrieving country name from database, I need in each page to appear its own country name .
sorry , This is the first time to deal with Google maps I see a lot of plugin but it's not finally ..I want to sent to google maps the name of country, and I receive the map of this country

Comment: Your question makes no sense whatsoever. Please try to explain more detailed what you are trying to do and what isn't working.

Comment: I want to sent to google maps the name of country, and I receive the map of this country ..can you understand my question ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser.html)? (implemented using Natural Earth Data publicly available in Fusion Tables)

Comment: like this map but the name of country not chooses for dropdown menu the name of country come to map in hidden input @geocodezip

Comment: view the source, download it to your computer and change it like you want.

Answer (score 2):

Download a dataset, like this one: http://blog.stavi.sh/country-list-iso-3166-codes-latitude-longitud

This will give you the rough location of each country.

Next just construct a map for each country and centre it on the points given in the above data.

Comment: I want to sent to google maps the name of country, and I receive the map of this country

Comment: Then you'll want the geocoder, look here for an example - http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DAfghanistan

Comment: IS there any plugin do that ?

Comment: Not that I know of. If not you could always write one ;)

Comment: thanks a lot I use this plugin [link](http://www.wimagguc.com/projects/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps/)